# Banach - Steinhaus Theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification

I'm trying to understand the Banach-Steinhaus theorem and his proof.The theorem states:

> We choose $(E, \|.\|_E)$ a Banach space and $(F, \|.\|_F)$ a normed
> vector space. If  $A\subset\mathcal{L}_c(E,F)$,
> then either ${(\|f\|_L)_{f \in A}} $ is
> bounded or $\exists x \in E$ s.t. $\sup_{f \in A} \| f(x) \|_F = +\infty$.

First of I cannot imagine anything under this theorem.
In the first steps of the proof, we choose $k\in \mathbb{N}$ and define the set $\mathcal{O}_k= \{ x \in E\ | \sup_{f \in A} \| f(x) \|_F > k \}$. We then want to show that $\mathcal{O}_k$ is open in $E$. For this choose $g \in A$ and define $V_g^k= \{ x \in E\ | 
 \ \| g(x)\|_F > k\}$.

Now why is $\bigcup_{g \in A} V^k_g \subset \mathcal{O}_k$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It suffices to prove that for fixed $g \in A$ we have that $V_g^k \subseteq \mathcal{O}_k$. For $x \in V_g^k$, $$\sup_{f \in A} \|f(x)\|_F \geq \|g(x)\|_F > k$$ so that $x \in \mathcal{O}_k$ (the first inequality follows since $g \in A$ and the second since $x \in V_g^k$).